# Adding watermark

Tags: graphics

I have simple question of adding a watermark with predefined position. I need to put it with the setting given below.
 Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% change accordingly
  angle=0,       %% change accordingly
  opacity=.6,    %% change accordingly
  color =black,  %% change accordingly
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{AA_Deutsche.png}};    ***How can I put my image to upper right corner of each image.***
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}

.
.
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}

\newpage
.
.
\end{document}
```

I'm attaching the image and desired setting . Currently I'm using Adobe to add the watermark with these setting (Attached please see setting image)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not understand your settings. Here is an example with `background` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% change accordingly
  angle=0,       %% change accordingly
  opacity=.6,    %% change accordingly
  color =black,  %% change accordingly
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ([yshift=11pt,xshift=5pt]current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};    %% yshift and xshift for example only
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, `texdoc background` from terminal.

Comment: In this case, there's no need to use a `tikzpicture` in the contents; you can simply say: `\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=.6,
  color =black,
  contents={\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}},
  vshift=11pt,
  hshift=5pt
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\usepackage{watermark}
```

and according to [watermark documentation](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/watermark.pdf):

> Examples of using watermarks are shown in the `ncccropmark` package.